# How do you prevent the current user folder from opening when starting Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When you run Windows Explorer, the current user folder is always fully expanded, taking up a lot of space on the screen. But rarely is the current user folder the folder that I want to go to when starting Windows Explorer.

So, is there a way to prevent the current user folder from opening every time I start Windows Explorer?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Mine is Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `Organize / Folder and search options` turn off **Show all folders** (you can also access the option by right-clicking on empty space in the left Explorer pane). Now simply pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> should start Explorer rooted at *Computer* without the user folder expanded (at least it works that way for me in Windows 7).

You can also change the *Target* of the Windows Explorer Start Menu shortcut to something like `%windir%\explorer.exe /e,C:\` to open at C:\ instead of Libraries (or whatever the default location is).

Finally, if you want to remove the user folder completely from the navigation pane irrespective of whether **Show all folders** is enabled or not, follow the tutorial [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/48123-user-folder-add-remove-navigation-pane.html).

Comment: That worked beautifully!