# Windows Explorer left pane has changed

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

The left-hand pane of my Windows Explorer has changed in a negative way. The picture below is what explorer looks like right after opening a new window.

[image: Left pane]

From what I can tell, the original nodes of the explorer tree (Libraries, Homegroup, Computer, etc.) have all been moved under my desktop for some reason. This has really cluttered things up.

I have tried "sfc /scannow" because it was the only thing I could think of, and it didn't fix anything.

For people not on Windows 7 (thank you for your help), [Explorer should look something like these do](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=windows%207%20explorer).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you prevent the current user folder from opening when starting Windows Explorer?](http://superuser.com/questions/510173/how-do-you-prevent-the-current-user-folder-from-opening-when-starting-windows-ex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> Right click in the navigation pane
>
> Uncheck **Show all Folders**
>
> Should be back to how you were expecting

Comment: Yay! So this answers your question?